# Retrieve value of netCDF global attribute by name in Python

Tags: python, global-variables, netcdf

How do I retrieve the value of a global attribute from a netCDF file in Python by its name?

I have tried:

```
value = ncfile.getncattr(ncfile, global_attribute_name)
```

but I get the error:

```
NameError: name 'global_attribute_name' is not defined
```

I have also read the section of the [netCDF4 API documentation](https://unidata.github.io/netcdf4-python/netCDF4/index.html) that deals with global attributes, but I'm sure there's something I don't understand with the syntax.

Can anyone help? I'm an R user moving over to Python, please be gentle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how it worked for me:

```
value = ncfile.getncattr('my_attr')
```

Answer (score 2):

`global_attribute_name` is a parameter. You should replace it with the name of the attribute you are trying to retrieve, wrapped in quotes. So, let's say the name of the attribute is `my_attr`, then use

```
value = ncfile.getncattr(ncfile, 'my_attr')
```

Comment: Thank-you.  I did try that, but received another error - probably related to something else in the script I'm working on.  I'll accept your answer though.  Cheers.